# Como Imprimir uma lista de números somados em sequência?

Tags: java

Programa:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Long> lista = new ArrayList();

    long k = 0;

    for (long a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {

    k = k+2; 

    lista.add(k);

  }  

    System.out.println("Soma="+lista);
 }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece estar tudo certo, mas na verdade isso não é uma "sequência somada".
O que o programa faz é somente somar os números de `2` em `2`. (2+2+2+2+2)
Assim dessa forma de `1` a `10` ficam `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20].`
O que eu realmente busco é uma soma em sequência e não somar de `2` em `2`, ou `3` em `3`, ou `4` em `4`.

Exemplo: `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10` (estaria subindo) isso seria a sequência!
E não uma "soma parada" (1+1+1+1+1).

Igual pra `2` =  `2+4+6+8+10`

Igual pra `3` =  `3+6+9+12`

Igual pra `4` =  `4+8+12+16`

No meu programa imprime: Soma=`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]` (2+2+2+2+2,etc.)

Se ele estivesse na "sequência somada" de `2`.

Esse seria o resultado: Soma=`[2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90, 110]` (2+4+6+8+10,etc.)

Se ele estivesse na "sequência somada" de `3`.

Esse seria o resultado: Soma=`[3, 9, 18, 30, 45, 63, 84, 108, 135, 165]` (3+6+9+12+15,etc.)

Comment: Pode adicionar o código deste programa que originou este problema?

Comment: Seria bom colocar o código, e não um _screenshot_ dele. Tem a ferramenta de formatação para isso na barra, indicada pelo ícone `{ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a cada iteração do for, ele vai apenas acrescentar 2, e não somar de acordo com o múltiplo do número base. Para isso você precisa ir incrementando o valor com a multiplicação do iterador do laço e da base(no caso do código da pergunta, 2):

```
k = k + (a * 2);
```

Você pode trocar o `2` por uma variável int que represente o valor do qual você quer essa sequencia somada, assim:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    List<Long> lista = new ArrayList();

    long k = 0;

    //aqui você pode trocar por outros números que quer
    //fazer a sequencia tendo ele como base
    int base = 2; 

    for (long a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {

       k += (base*a); 

       lista.add(k);
    }  

    System.out.println("Soma="+lista);
 }
```

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/247D1A).

Comment: Funcionou muito Obrigado!!!! @diegofm

Comment: @Rafaelzinho disponha! :)

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar colocar mais uma variável.

> K-> a base da soma
>   x-> o numero fixo
>   y-> o numero que crescera com o numero fixo

A conta vai ficar algo parecido com isso(supondo que o x seja 2):

```
y = 0; 
K = 0;
for(int a=0; a<=10;a++){    
   y = y+2;   //=>(x=2)  
   K = K+y;
}
```